# OS X 10.9 privacy controls: what's the right code signing identity & provisioning during debug?

Tags: xcode5, code-signing, provisioning-profile, osx-gatekeeper

When my app is run via Xcode in the Debug configuration, it cannot access the user's address book (`ABPeoplePickerView` is blank). However, when the app is built for direct or App Store distribution then it has access to the address book.

This seems like a provisioning/codesigning issue. However, no valid code sign identity for the debug config seems to grant the app permission to read the contacts when running under debug. The app is using the same entitlements file under debug as under release.

This seems to have cropped up with the installation of 10.9.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disregard. For posterity -- the problem is that when running the app through Xcode, the app's access controls are appropriated by Xcode's.  By enabling Contacts access for *Xcode* in the System Preferences, the app now has access to contacts.